# How to select rows that contains data from a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I want to select data in a row

```
Name DOB Sunsign    Name(Column)
a     1     Ar          d
b     2     Le          c
c     3     Lr
d     4     CP
```

Now the new cell must show the following data

```
Name DOB Sunsign
c     3     Lr
d     4     CP
```

Comment: I tried the find function but firstly was not able to iterate all the entries in the Name(Column and then was not able to select the specified row)

Comment: You can use `vlookup`? Or is the problem that the first column in the new cell must be sorted?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the Excel autofilter functionality?

[image]

Alternatively, if you don't want to click the filter but use a separate column to specify the filter values, you can try the method described on [this page](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3656-excel-autofilter-based-on-cell-value.html):

> 1. Go the worksheet that you want to auto filter the date based on cell value you entered.
> 2. Right click the sheet tab, and select View Code from the context menu, in the popped out Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications
>      window, please copy and paste the following code into the blank Module
>      window, see screenshot:
>
> VBA code: auto filter data according to entered cell value:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Updateby Extendoffice 20160606
   If Target.Address = Range("E2").Address Then
       Range("A1:C20").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("E1:E2")
   End If
End Sub
```

> Note: In the above code, A1:C20 is your data range that you want to
>   filter, E2 is the target value that you want to filter based on, and
>   E1:E2 is your criteria cell will be filtered based on. You can change
>   them to your need.
>
> 3. Now, when you entering the criteria in cell E1 and E2 and press Enter key, your data will be filtered by the cell values
>      automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have added 4 rows just to give an example, my file has 37 rows with 3 columns which consist of the names | dob | sun sign now there is another column which contains names of 14 players whos rows details I need to fetch, I am having trouble in iterating through that 3rd column.

Comment: If you follow the second method, you can change the CriteriaRange in the VBA code to fit your requirements (I think). I have not tried it out, let me know if you run into issues.